# ImageIO write save a black image

Tags: java, swing, javax.imageio

I used

```
BufferedImage bi= new BufferedImage(320,240,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
```

`ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);`

to save an image but save a black image. I can not understand what is the problem.

Comment: That is not enough to know what is the problem. Most likely `bi` is black, but you don't show how you create its contents.

Comment: If you don't put _anything_ on the canvas, it will be black. This can also happen by mistake, of course. Please add your code before this line. What did you do with `bi` before?

Comment: how did you manipulate the `bi` Image?! this is because the default pixel values is 0, and it means black.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm just passing by and have no experience with BufferedImage, but `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @Marc-Andre it's OK, it means that the image type is grayscale image.

Comment: What did you expect? If you save a black image, it will be black. I can not understand what is the problem... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As it was suggested already, the default pixel values are zeros (RGB(0,0,0)) in a `BufferedImage`, so by this line:

```
BufferedImage bi= new BufferedImage(320,240,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
```

you create a black image. So the result is exactly what is expected in this case.

If you want to create a white one for example, you can do this:

```
BufferedImage bi= new BufferedImage(320,240,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
Graphics gc = bi.getGraphics();
gc.setColor(Color.white);
gc.fillRect(0,0,320,240);
```

before saving.